# Most efficient way to use AWS SQS (with Golang)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, gzip, amazon-sqs

When using the AWS SQS (Simple Queue Service) you pay for each request you make to the service (push, pull, ...). There is a maximum of 256kb for each message you can send to a queue.

To save money I'd like to buffer messages sent to my Go application before I send them out to SQS until I have enough data to efficiently use the 256kb limit.

Since my Go application is a webserver, my current idea is to use a string mutex and append messages as long as I would exceed the 256kb limit and then issue the SQS push event. To save even more space I could gzip every single message before appending it to the string mutex.

I wonder if there is some kind of gzip stream that I could use for this. My assumption is that gzipping all concatenated messages together will result in smaller size then gzipping every message before appending it to the string mutex. One way would be to gzip the string mutex after every append to validate its size. But that might be very slow.

Is there a better way? Or is there a total better approach involving channels? I'm still new to Go I have to admit.

Comment: Aside from the fact that buffering in memory will open you to data loss, how much will your time cost, and how many millions of requests will this cover if you don't do the work? Unless you're making pennies per hour, the answer should be clear.

Comment: The stdlib gzip is a stream: https://golang.org/pkg/compress/gzip/

Comment: You don't want to work with strings though, you want to work with byte slices.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the following approach

- Use a channel to accept incoming "internal" messages to a go routine
- In that go routine keep the messages in a "raw" format, so 10 messages is 10 raw uncompressed items
- Each time a new raw item arrives, compress all the raw messages into one.  If the size with the new message > 256k then compress messages EXCEPT the last one and push to SQS

This is computationally expensive.  Each individual message causes a full compression of all pending messages.  However it is efficient for SQS use

Answer (score 0):

You could guesstimate the size of the gzipped messages and calculate whether you've reached the max size threshold. Keep track of a message size counter and for every new message increment the counter by it's expected compressed size.  Do the actual compression and send to SQS only if your counter will exceed 256kb. So you could avoid compressing every time a new message comes in.
For a use-case like this, running a few tests on a sample set of messages should give the rough percentage of compression expected.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get focused on compression, eliminate redundant data that is known on both sides. This is what encodings like [msgpack](https://msgpack.org), [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org), and so on do.

Let's say all of your messages are a struct like this:

```golang
type Foo struct {
    bar string
    qux int
}
```

and you were thinking of encoding it as JSON. Then the most efficient you could do is:

```
{"bar":"whatever","qux",123}
```

If you wanted to just append all of those together in memory, you might get something like this:

```
{"bar":"whatever","qux",123}{"bar":"hello world","qux",0}{"bar":"answer to life, the universe, and everything","qux",42}{"bar":"nice","qux",69}
```

A really good compression algorithm might look at hundreds of those messages and identify the repetitiveness of `{"bar":"` and `","qux",`.

But compression has to do work to figure that out from your data each time.

If the receiving code already knows what "schema" (the `{"bar": some_string, "qux": some_int}` "shape" of your data) each message has, then you can just serialize the messages like this:

```
"whatever"123"hello world"0"answer to life, the universe, and everything"42"nice"69
```

Note that in this example encoding, you can't just start in the middle of the data and unambiguously find your place. If you have a bunch of messages such as `{"bar":"1","qux":2}`, `{"bar":"2","qux":3}`, `{"bar":"3","qux":4}`, then the encoding will produce: `"1"2"2"3"3"4`, and you can't just start in the middle and know for sure if you're looking at a number or a string - you have to count from the ends. Whether or not this matters will depend on your use case.

You can come up with other simple schemes that are more unambiguous or make the code for writing or reading messages easier or simpler, like using a field separator or message separator character which is escaped in your encoding of the other data (just like how `\` and `"` would be escaped in quoted JSON strings).

If you can't have the receiver just know/hardcode the expected message schema - if you need the full flexibility of something like JSON and you always unmarshal into something like a `map[string]interface{}` or whatever - then you should consider using something like [BSON](http://bsonspec.org).

Of course, you can't use msgpack, protobuf, AVRO, or BSON directly - they need a medium that allows arbitrary bytes like `0x0`. And according to the [AWS SQS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> Q: What kind of data can I include in a message?
>
> Amazon SQS messages can contain up to 256 KB of text data, including XML, JSON and unformatted text. The following Unicode characters are accepted:
>
> #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20 to #xD7FF] | [#xE000 to #xFFFD] | [#x10000 to #x10FFFF]

So if you want to aim for maximum space efficiency for your exact usecase, you'd have to write your own code which use the techniques from those encoding schemes, but only used bytes which bytes are allowed in SQS messages.

Relatedly, if you have a lot of integers, and you know most of them are small (or clump around a certain spot of the number line, so that by adding a constant offset to all of them you can make most of them small), you can use one of the [variable length quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity) techniques to encode all of those integers. In fact several of those common encoding schemes mentioned above use variable length quantities in their encoding of integers. If you use a "piece size" of six (6) bits (instead of the standard implicitly assumed piece size of eight (8) bits to match a byte) then you can use base64. *Not* full base64 encoding, because the padding will completely defeat the purpose - just map from the 64 possible values that fit in six bits to the 64 distinct ASCII characters that base64 uses.

Anyway, unless you know your data has a lot repetition (but not the kind that you can just not send, like the same field names in every message) I would start with all of that, and only then would I look at compression.

Even so, if you want minimal size, I would aim for LZMA, and if you want minimal computing overhead, I would use LZ4. Gzip is not bad per se - if it's much easier to use gzip then just use it - but if you're optimizing for either size or for speed, there are better options. I don't know if gzip is even a good "middle ground" of speed and output size and working memory size - it's pretty old and maybe there's compression algorithms which are just strictly superior in speed and output and memory size by now. I think gzip, depending on implementation, also includes headers and framing information (like version metadata, size, checksums, and so on), which if you really need to minimize for size you probably don't want, and in the context of SQS messages you probably don't need.